# Magento Configurable Product: Add custom options in cart like separate item

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I set up a configurable product in Magento, I add in associated products colors and button and in custom options I add 3 options.

[image]

[image]

In frontend my product look like in this image:

[image]

All I want is when I select one of the 3 options (Sim Cards) for example when I select Vodafone and press add to cart, the custom option not have the price, I want to be added in cart like a separate product.

My cart now is

[image]

So I want to have this Vodafone Custom Option Separate with their own order and their price. My cart need to be like this

[image]

I need this vodafone option to have their own price and order because Is a sim card and their payment must to be montly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement the sim card as related product instead of custom option.